# Spark: Error While Writing DataFrame to CSV

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, hdfs, spark-csv

I'm trying to write a dataframe to a *.csv file to HDFS using Databricks' spark-csv_2.10 dependency. The dependency seems to work fine as I'm able to read a .csv file to a DataFrame. But when I perform a write, I get the following error. The exception comes after the header is written to the file.

```
18/06/21 21:41:58 WARN hdfs.DFSClient: Caught exception
java.lang.InterruptedException
at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
at java.lang.Thread.join(Thread.java:1281)
at java.lang.Thread.join(Thread.java:1355)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.closeResponder(DFSOutputStream.java:967)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.endBlock(DFSOutputStream.java:705)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.run(DFSOutputStream.java:894)
```

This is a simplified version of the code I use

```
DataFrame df = sqlContext.read().format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
                        .option("header", "true")
                        .option("inferSchema", "true")
                        .option("delimiter", "|")
                        .load("/user/abc/data.csv");
df.registerTempTable("empTable");
DataFrame result = sqlContext.sql("SELECT department, avg(salary) as avgSalary FROM empTable GROUP BY department").cache();
result.write()
      .format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
      .option("header", "true")
      .save("/user/abc/csv/"); //InterruptedException comes here
//The directory "/user/abc/csv/" gets created and it even has temp files.
```

The write works fine when I change the query to `SELECT department, salary FROM empTable`.

Can anyone help me with this?

**Edit:** As requested by Chandan here is the result of `result.show();`

```
+----------+---------+
|department|avgSalary|
+----------+---------+
|   Finance|   5000.0|
|    Travel|   5000.0|
+----------+---------+
```

I use Spark 1.6.0 and spark-csv_2.10:1.5.0

Comment: Which version of Spark are you using?

Comment: Do you have the permissions to write to the HDFS directory used in the code?

Comment: can you use save("/user/abc/csv/test"); instead of save("/user/abc/csv/");

Comment: @PhaniKumarYadavilli Would that make a difference? Because both /csv and /test would be directories. Plus, the same path works fine when I change the query run by `SQLContext.sql()`

Comment: Usually, the code should work. Because when I am trying in my local your code is working fine. Either you have permission issue or it could be treated as some malformed URI.

Comment: @PhaniKumarYadavilli The write fails only when I use the GROUP BY query. It works when I use a simple SELECT. I don't think permissions are a problem here

Comment: @Shaido I use Spark 1.6.0

Answer (score 0):

Is it the unix file system or HDFS you are writing to. I am able to execute with the above code. Are you able to see the result DataFrame. Try result.show and post the result here. Will check what is the issue. If possible please post the complete log

Try to save it in parquet and see if it’s working. If it’s working then there must be some issue with csv which we can check. It’s working for me. No issue with query tried in spark 2.2 and 1.6.3. try to write in your local unix file system. I am thinking it might be some issue with HDFS. Your code seems to be correct

Comment: It's partially working. It writes the csv file but only manages to write the header and then gets the `InterruptedException` before writing the data. The exception gets caught and another attempt is made with a new file. Again, the exception comes after writing the header. I changed `option("header", "true")` to `false` and the Exception doesn't come anymore. But there are around 200 files out of which only 2 have the data.

Answer (score 0):

You can ignore this warning. It's a bug in Hadoop.

There is an issue for this: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HDFS-10429